# MYSQL: "Access denied for user 'X'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" PYTHON

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I'm trying to access the database using python but it's just not working. When I access a remote database everything is fine. But local there is some kind of problem. What I'm doing wroing here? I've tryied some things that I found on intener do grant access but they did not work

Local users:
[image]

Code used:

[image]

Message recieved

[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you read the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)? - The given answer seems to apply to your problem as well (If I'm interpreting your phpmyadmin Screenshot correctly)

Comment: Sorry! Confused!! Is the database you are trying to access (local i.e. on the same machine as the code) or as you suggest (remote i.e. on another machine)????

Comment: _Side Note_ Granting `All Privilages` to this user seems like OverKill. Grant only what the app requires and only on the databases that the app requires

Comment: I've tryied to edit the users.. I excluded the anonymous users and changed the host to '127.0.0.1', 'localhost', '%', '192.168.0.116'(my local ip) but it does't work.. Every thins is local here. I remove All Privileges and let only "data" commands.

Comment: Also.. This is MAMP's MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of testing I finally found out what was the problem! After some alterations in the mysql users and no results everything work just fine when I added the PORT to mysql database!

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="userpython",passwd="root",db="bigdata",port=8886)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a port number did not work for me. When granted privileges to os user which runs the python script worked.

```
sudo mysql -u root -h localhost -p
grant all privileges on database_name.* to 'os_user'@'localhost' identified by 
'password' with grant option;
```

Comment: your solution didn't work for me - is there any thing I should change /

Answer (score 0):

The port number is missing in the `MySQLdb.connect()` function.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have added all the parameters correctly,
confirm valid username and password.
Example below:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(
host="localhost",
user="username",
password="password",
database="database_name",
)
```